# Distributed services sharing same data schema

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, data-modeling, microservices

We are building a Spring Boot based web application which consists of a central API server and multiple remote workers. We tried to embrace the idea of microservices so each component is built as a separate Spring Boot App. But they do share a lot of same data schema for the objects being handled across components, thus currently the JPA model definitions in code are duplicated in each component's project. Every time something changes we need to remember to change it everywhere and this results in poor compatibility between different versions across components.

So I'm wondering if this is the best we can do here, or is there better ways to manage the components code in such scenario?

To be more specific, we use both MySQL and Redis for data storage and both are accessed by all components. Redis is actually serving as one tool of data communication between components.

Comment: Are you only using the classes in different services for JSON de/serialization or are you actually using the same database schema for different services? In the latter case, can different services read and write from the same tables in your schema?

Comment: @dunni Sorry, should have been clearer. It's the former case, majorly central server will serialize the object and send the serialized data throught REST call or Redis, then workers deserialize them using the same classes in code. Currently different components don't access same relational DB.